# can't have been vs. couldn't have been

Tags: differences, modal-verbs

I don't understand when and why to use ***can't have been***. It seems so strange to me.

Comment: You **can't have been** paying attention when your English teacher covered this! :)

Comment: hahah :) I am from the Czech republic. My English teacher doesn't teach us this kind of things. I think she herself has no idea, because to her we don't have to know more than what is necessary for passing the school-leaving exam. Lame, I know.

Answer (score 11):

You're right; *can't have been* is strange.

For one thing, *can* is a modal auxiliary verb; all modal auxiliary verbs are irregular as hell.
For another, *can't* is a negative, and negatives with modals have different syntax.

Of course, a great deal depends on what the predicate of the sentence is.
*Can't have been* is just a string of auxiliaries, not a predicate.
It could have a predicate noun or a predicate adjective or a predicate complement

- *They can't have been so drunk that they didn't notice their car had been stolen.*  (pred adj)
- *They can't have been doctors; they were wearing nurse's uniforms.* (pred noun)
- *It can't have been playing the wrong note that infuriated him so.* (pred comp clause)

In each of these examples, note that the corresponding affirmative sentence is terrible:

- **They can have been so drunk that they didn't notice their car had been stolen.*  (pred adj)
- **They can have been doctors; they weren't wearing nurse's uniforms.* (pred noun)
- **It can have been playing the wrong note that infuriated him so.* (pred comp clause)

This is because the epistemic sense of *can* is a [negative polarity item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf),
and requires a negative trigger. Without a negative, you can't use *can* epistemically.

This is a fact like the fact that epistemic *will* ('be scheduled to, be sposta', sometimes called "future tense")  is not allowed in hypothetical clauses (**If it will rain tomorrow, the picnic is cancelled*).
Very strange syntax and many irregularities [with modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf).

Comment: Bill's answer notwithstanding, it seems to me that are many contexts where *can/could* are effectively interchangeable. For example, I don't see any real distinction between your first example and *"They **couldn't** have been so drunk that they didn't notice"*. Is there any simple reason why the "corresponding affirmative" doesn't work with your example, but it does with *"They **could** have been so drunk that they didn't notice"* (one denies that possibility, the other allows that it might be true).

Comment: _Couldn't_ is better in all of these cases, because its epistemic sense is very close to that of _can_, and epistemic _could_ is not restricted to negative contexts like epistemic _can_. That's why _can't have been_ sounds odd; yes it's grammatical there, but why use a special restricted form when the normal form is _couldn't_?

Answer (score 7):

All right. I've done some research concerning *can't have been vs. couldn't have been*.

To remind meanings and uses of *couldn't have*  :

- it is used in past hypothetical conditionals - *can't have* can not be substituted
- expresses impossibility in past time
- embodies the root meaning (ability or capability) of the modals can and could - that they didn't have the ability or skill to.

***Can't have*** and ***couldn't have*** share a **similar degree of probability**. They are equal in meaning when they express the impossibility of something.

The differences:

1. - *"Can't have been"* suggests that it happened **more recently**. It expresses a judgment about a recent action or situation, a context in which the issues are still fresh and relevant to the present.
     (e.g. Can you check my homework? I'm quite sure *I can't have found* every bug.)
   - *"Couldn't have been"* suggests that it was **further in the past**.
     (e.g. As a young woman who had never given birth before, she *couldn't have known* what the experience of childbirth would be like.)
2. *Can't have* is used to express **negative obligation** or **permission**, while *couldn't have* carries no such meaning. This use of *can't have* means "You are not allowed to have (written...)."
   (e.g. You have to write it during the class, you *can't have written* it beforehand.)

Though *can't have* is used much less than *couldn't have*.

Answer (score -2):

You'll find can't have ... ed vs. couldn't have ...ed explained in a detailed way here:
http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00108.htm

Comment: This answer contains no information beyond a link. When Pearson Longman next rearrange their website (and corporations do this all the time), the link will break and your answer will contain no information at all. Please at least give a summary of the page you're linking to.

Comment: It's now September 2022 and the link is still working. A very useful link because Pearson is a reliable source.